# What's the reason to specify the type of a var in an XML file?

Tags: android

I m trying to learn ANDROID app programming.
I red that in the XML file  I have to use @type/name_var to call a var.
What's the reason to specify the type of a var?
Why I can t write @name_var?
What's the role of the type in an XML file?
Sorry for my bad english,
I hope you will understand me.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it simple, lets imagine a variable named `apple` in your resources as below:

> dimension -> apple
>
> string -> apple
>
> color -> apple

Now, in order to identify which `apple` you want, you must need to identify its container type.

And that is how we make use of:

> @dimen/apple
>
> @string/apple
>
> @color/apple